# Prepare Online and On-Premise version of web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, web-publishing

I have an application which we have to developed for two purpose

1. Online - There will be a super admin user you will create companies in the system and these companies can access their system on our application. For example our application is hosted on **example.com** so admin will login at **example.com/admin** and he creates a company and assign him a URL **example.com/company**. Now company users can use their company URL (**example.com/company**) and start using the system.
2. On-Premise - In this option application will be deployed on company's own hardware and only company's part of the application will be available for them. admin (**domain.com/admin**) section will not be available in On-Premise option.

Is there any way to do both the things in same web project and while publishing project for On-Premise use exclude the admin portion files otherwise complete application will be published.

Answer (score 0):

What about using build configurations to exclude certain folders by settings their build action?

Then you could add a configurtion called OnPremise and edit the project file to set Build action to exclude for the admin folder.

Something like the second anser here: [Different build action for debug and release builds in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671809/different-build-action-for-debug-and-release-builds-in-visual-studio)